# Pass parameters to view but not using them

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I have a view:

```
def product_details(request, brand_id, slug, product_id):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
    return render(request, 'product_details.html',
              {'product': product})
```

`urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       url(r'^$', 'core.views.show_brands', name='brands'),
                       url(r'^(?P<brand_id>\d+)/(?P<slug>[-\w\d]+)/$', 'core.views.brand_products', name='brand_products'),
                       url(r'^(?P<brand_id>\d+)/(?P<slug>[-\w\d]+)/(?P<product_id>\d+)/$', 'core.views.product_details', name='product_detail'),
                       )
```

The question is: should I pass `brand_id` and `slug` if I don't use them? I pass for human-readable url. Url example: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/brands/1/coca_cola/3/`

Comment: What happen if you remove `bran_id` and `slug`?

Comment: @Gocht, remove from the view? The getting: `product_details() got an unexpected keyword argument 'brand_id'`

Comment: remove from the view definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need the parameters, you can make them optional for the view and leave them in the URL like so:

```
def product_details(request, product_id):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
    return render(request, 'product_details.html',
              {'product': product})
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       url(r'^(\d+)?/([-\w\d]+)?/(?P<product_id>\d+)/$', 'core.views.product_details', name='product_detail'),
                       )
```

Notice the "?" after the first two matched regular expressions, making them optional. This means you can leave them out of the view, but reverse('product_detail', brand_id, slug, product_id) will still return a legible URL.

Comment: How can I get value `brand_id` in `brand_products` url then?

Comment: just add the parentheses & parameter name back in, `url(r'^(?P<brand_id>\d+)/[-\w\d]+/$', 'core.views.brand_products', name='brand_products')` and add the parameter back into your view.

Comment: it's not the solution. Because when I go to `brand_products` url,  an url looks like:`http://127.0.0.1:8000/brands/1/coca_cola/`, but when I choose some product and go to `product_detail` url, it looks like: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/brands/0/-/3/`. So `brand_id` and `slug` aren't showed. `0` and `-` are showed instead

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize reverse() would return gibberish. I've updated my answer to correct my oversight, let me know / accept my answer if it works.

Answer (score 0):

views.py

```
def product(request, id, slug):
 context = {}
 context['product'] = get_object_or_404(Product, id=id, slug=slug)
 return render(request, 'html', context)
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^product/(?P<slug>\w+)/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.product, name='product')
```